# Как отобразить картинку, загруженную из базы данных, на странице JSF

Tags: java, java-ee, jsf

Реализовываю интернет-магазин. Хочется добиться подобного отображения товаров

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Товары находятся в базе данных MySQL и, соответственно, картинки тоже. Возникла проблема: как отобразить картинку на странице? И как добиться подобного расположения информации о товаре? Думаю, можно делать как-то так:

```
<ui:repeat value="#{SomeBean.goods}" var="good">
    <div>...</div>
<ui:repeat>
```

А в переменной `good` как раз и будет вся информация о товаре: `id`, `image`, `price` и т.д. Сам тег `ui:repeat` поместить в flex box с параметром `flex-flow: row wrap`, ну и настроить `justify-content` и `align-items`. Мне интересно, я хотя бы в правильном направлении думаю?

Сделал как и советовали, но картинка так и не показывается

`index.xhtml`

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8' ?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
      xmlns:h="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/html"
      xmlns:ui="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/facelets">


    <h:body>

        <ui:composition template="/templates/index/template.xhtml">

            <ui:define name="content">

                <h:dataTable id="goods" value="#{goodController.goodList}" var="good" cellspacing="10px">

                    <h:column>
                        #{good.goodName}
                    </h:column>

                    <h:column>
                        <h:graphicImage value="/image?id=#{good.goodID}" width="30px" height="30px" />
                    </h:column>

                    <h:column>
                        #{good.price}
                    </h:column>

                </h:dataTable>

            </ui:define>

        </ui:composition>

    </h:body>


</html>
```

`ImageServlet`

```
package servlets;

import controllers.GoodController;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.OutputStream;
import java.sql.Blob;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.annotation.WebServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

@WebServlet("/image/*")
public class ImageServlet extends HttpServlet {

    protected void processRequest(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
        response.setContentType("image/jpg");
        try (OutputStream out = response.getOutputStream()) {
            long id = Integer.valueOf(request.getParameter("id"));
            GoodController goodController = (GoodController) request.getSession(false).getAttribute("goodController");
            Blob image = goodController.getImage(id);
            long imageLength = image.length();

            response.setContentLengthLong(imageLength);
            out.write(image.getBytes(1, (int) imageLength));
        } catch (SQLException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(ImageServlet.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
            throws ServletException, IOException {
        processRequest(request, response);
    }

    @Override
    protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
            throws ServletException, IOException {
        processRequest(request, response);
    }

    @Override
    public String getServletInfo() {
        return "Short description";
    }
}
```

`GoodController`

```
@ManagedBean(eager = true)
@SessionScoped
public class GoodController implements Serializable {
    public GoodController() {
    }
    //...
}
```

Comment: Похожий вопрос на английском, есть два подхода в принятом ответе: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30606503/show-image-as-byte-from-database-as-graphic-image-in-jsf-page

Comment: @defaultlocale, можете посмотреть. Я сделал так как и советовал BalusC, но картинки не показываются.

Comment: Нужно бы поподробнее разобраться что происходит не так. Посмотрите в полученной странице какие формируются адреса для картинок (`img src`). Если адреса получаются правильные, проверьте вызывается ли сервлет и корректно ли он отрабатывает.

Comment: И код отличается от кода по ссылке там ID картинки прописывается в URL (`/image/#{someBean.imageId}`) и парсится, в то время как у Вас передается как параметр. Подозреваю, что сервлет не вызывается.

Comment: ещё и '@WebServlet("/image/*")' не охватывает адрес изображения. идёте по '/image?id=...' а ожидается '/image/...'

Comment: Изменил `value` у `h:graphicImage` теперь: `value="/image/#{good.goodID}"`. Считываю его так: `long id = Long.valueOf(request.getPathInfo().substring(1));`. Адреса для картинок формируются следующие: `/java_web_5/image/1`. Но картинка при этом не отображается (ее размер `0x0`). Получается сервлет не запускается?

Comment: Отследите, что происходит в сервлете. Можете вывести в лог `request.getPathInfo` и проверьте, появляются ли записи. Если можете, то подключитесь к серверу приложений для отладки, тогда отлаживать будет удобнее.

Comment: @defaultlocale, понял, почему не работает. В строке `GoodController goodController = (GoodController) request.getSession(false).getAttribute("goodController");` метод `getAttribute` возвращает `null`. Я добавил обьявление `GoodController`. Можете подсказать в чем проблема?

Comment: @defaultlocale, заменил строку `GoodController goodController = (GoodController) request.getSession(false).getAttribute("goodController");` на `GoodController goodController = new GoodController();` и все заработало :)  Но вопрос остается в силе. Почему, все же, не находило аттрибут сессии?

Comment: @notaProgrammer не могу точно сказать в чем проблема. `@Inject`-ить контроллер пробовали? Точно `getAttribute` возвращает null, а не `getSession`?

Comment: @defaultlocale Точно `getAttribute` возвращает `null`. Инжектить не пробовал.